# powershell json object with square brackets

Tags: json, powershell

I have an import of 1+ emails that have to be added to a json object. A foreach loop checks to see if the emails are valid (code not addded to this example). When the import contains 2+ cases, the format of the json object is correct:

```
[
{
    "Name":  "John Doe",
    "Email":  "email@gmail.com"
},
{
    "Name":  "Jane Doe",
    "Email":  "email@live.com"
}
]
```

Namely, square brackets with each object in curly brackets, separated by comma.
But when the foreach loop only returns 1 valid email, the format becomes:

```
{
    "Name":  "John Doe",
    "Email":  "email@gmail.com"
}
```

This is the code I am running:

```
        $body = foreach($row in $mailinglistimp) 
                             {                             
                                 @{
                                 Email=$row.EPOSTADR 
                                 Name=$row.KUNDE_NM
                                 }
                              }
        $body_json = ConvertTo-json $body
```

How can I force the object to look like this with only one item in the foreach loop?

```
[
{
    "Name":  "John Doe",
    "Email":  "email@gmail.com"
},
]
```

On a related note, a similar problem was solved by using [int[]] $ids inside another json object, but I cant get a similar code to work using [string[]].

Comment: `$body = @( foreach(...){...} )`

Comment: Fantastic! That seems to solve my problem. Knew it had to be something simple

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat unlikely if you ask me, because you want to declare an array which contains a single item. PowerShell will always see this like a single item and won't add square brackets (array declaration for JSON). But I ran into the same issue when I was making a script to update changes in TOPdesk. So this might help someone.

```
$requestObject = @()
$action = "Buy a new laptop"
$status = "Rejected"
    if($Action){
        $requestObject += @{
            op = "add"
            path = "/progressTrail"
            value = $Action
        }
    }

    if($Status){
        $requestObject += @{
            op = "replace"
            path = "/status"
            value = $Status
        }
    }

    if($requestObject){
        if($requestObject.Count -eq 1){
            $requestBody = "[$($requestObject | ConvertTo-Json)]"
        }else{
            $requestBody = $requestObject | ConvertTo-Json
        }
}
```

The following output is generated:

```
[
{
    "path":  "/progressTrail",
    "op":  "add",
    "value":  "Buy a new laptop"
},
{
    "path":  "/status",
    "op":  "replace",
    "value":  "Rejected"
}
```

]

Now if you leave $status empty for instance, you will get the following:

```
   [{
    "path":  "/progressTrail",
    "op":  "add",
    "value":  "Buy a new laptop"
}]
```

Note that I force the square brackets, when there is only one item in my array ($requestObject.Count -eq 1). This is not very nice imo, but it does the trick.